# Button to next display in matplotlib

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, debugging, interface

I have a class object with an attribute `display(self)`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Obj:
    def display(self) -> None:
        fig = plt.figure()
        sub = fig.add_subplot()
        sub.plot(...)
        plt.show()
 
    def dostuff(self) -> 'stuff':            
        ...
        self.display()
        ...
        self.display()
        ...
        self.display()
        return
```

I use this function to have a better visual reference of how my `dostuff(self)` attribute is handling its task. It all works as intended, when the `self.display()` command is registered the scrypt pauses execution and plots stuff. However, to resume the only way is closing the matplotlib window manually and then the program reopens another one with the next changes.
Is there a way to implement a button or a better way to view the next changes without having to close and reopen a new window every single time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[plt.show](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.show.html) has parameter `block`. If you set it to `False`, then the execution is not blocked. Hope this helps.